# How to fixed this recursive (divide & conquer) process of finding maximum & minimum?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, max, min

To finding `maximum` & `minimum` in recursive and divide & conquer method, I code from a ***pseudocode***. But there is a problem with this code, I can't find `maximum` & `minimum`. The result of `maximum` & `minimum` is not correct here.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int num[50000], max1 = 0, min1 = 0, max2 = 0, min2 = 0;

void maxmin(int i, int j, int &max1, int &min2)
{
    if(i == j)
        max1 = min1 = num[i];
    else if(i == j - 1)
        {
            if(num[i] < num[j])
                {
                    max1 = num[j];
                    min1 = num[i];
                }
            else
                {
                    max1 = num[i];
                    min1 = num[j];
                }
        }
    else
    {
        int mid = (i + j) / 2;
        maxmin(i, mid, max1, min1);
        maxmin(mid+1, j, max2, min2);
        if(max1 < max2)
            max1 = max2;
        if(min1 > min2)
            min1 = min2;

    }
}

main()
{
    int n, i, minValue, maxValue;
    cout<<"No. of Data: ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"\nRange(min, max): ";
    cin>>minValue>>maxValue;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        num[i] = minValue+(rand()%(int)(maxValue-minValue+1));
    }
    maxmin(0, n-1, max1, min1);
    cout<<"\nMax: "<<max1<<"\tMin: "<<min1<<endl;
}
```

What is the problem with this ***pseudocode / code***??

Comment: I tried, `max1` & `min1` to be passed by reference by using `void maxmin(int I, int j, int &max1, &min1)`

Comment: Please provide the pseudocode you are following. You should find the errors on your own in your code. Use a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `maxmin(0, n-1, max1, min1);`, are you expecting `max1` and `max2` to be passed by reference? If so, you need to amend the function signature to:

```
void maxmin(int i, int j, int & max1, int & min2)
```

Comment: Yes I try this to be passed by reference, but it not working too.

Comment: @JahidulIslam In your question body, you suggested that you tried to modify the function invocation. But you need to modify the function *signature*, not the invocation. Though this depends on the logic of your code being correct.

Answer (score 1):

A Divide & Conquer recursive algorithm works by dividing work into the simplest case (generally one element) by recursively calling itself with a smaller problem, then combine the results of those calls. Mergesort is an excellent illustration of divide and conquer.

The Divide and Conquer algorithm is as follows:

1. Check for terminating condition (`start == stop`), and set `min` and `max` reference parameters to this array value (simplest case is one array element. in this case, this element is both the minimum and maximum of the one element).
2. Divide the array into left and right halves and make the recursive calls with those halves, saving into separate variables. Then "combine" the results of the calls by finding the minimum and maximum of the left and right calls.

Code implementing this algorithm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

void maxmin_divide_and_conquer(int arr[], int start, int stop, int &min, int & max)
{
    if (start == stop)
    {
        min = max = arr[start];
    }
    else
    {
        int midpoint = (start + stop) / 2;

        int leftMin;
        int leftMax;
        int rightMin;
        int rightMax;

        maxmin_divide_and_conquer(arr, start, midpoint, leftMin, leftMax);
        maxmin_divide_and_conquer(arr, midpoint + 1, stop, rightMin, rightMax);

        if (leftMin < rightMin)
            min = leftMin;
        else
            min = rightMin;

        if (leftMax > rightMax)
            max = leftMax;
        else
            max = rightMax;
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int size = 10;
    int arr[size] = { 99, 34, 15, 17, 19, 26, 18, 783, 14, -6 };

    int min;
    int max;
    maxmin_divide_and_conquer(arr, 0, size - 1, min, max);

    std::cout << "Divide and Conquer recursive --- " << '\n';
    std::cout << "Minimum is: " << min << '\n' << "Maximum is: " << max << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Minimum is: -6
Maximum is: 783
```

The differences here from your code are that I'm not using any global variables (your `min1` and `max2` are being used as global variables in the function), and this will be a big part of your problem. Recursion should generally use parameters and/or local variables to prevent outside information from affecting the call (in other words, recursive algorithms are generally self-contained, avoiding data outside of what is passes as a parameter and also avoiding side-effects from setting data other than parameters or return values).

I also don't see a need for the additional case of `i == j - 1`, since that just duplicates some of what the code to combine the results does.

Comment: Yeah, Thank you. But I can't express my questions, I think. Because I need not only recursive but also divide & conquer method for this.

Comment: Ah, divide & conquer would be a critical piece of information here. I'll see if I can make an update to my answer a little later.

Comment: @JahidulIslam I've updated my answer with a divide & conquer algorithm and notes about how this differs from what your attempt is doing.

Comment: @JahidulIslam If this answer was helpful, don't forget that you can mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with your pseudo code. Why max1 variable is used for two purpose here ? see my code of your version

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int Max(int x,int y){ //genarate the max number between to number
    return x>y?x:y; 
}
int Min(int x,int y){ //genarate the min number between to number
    return x<y?x:y;
}
void maxmin(int x, int y, int *number, int &max, int &min);
int main(){
    //*/
    freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
    freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
    //*/
    int nCase,nInput,number[10000],max,min;
    /*
     * nCase denotes the number of test case
     * nInput<10000 number of element in each test case
     * number[10000] number array to find max-min
     * max-min stores the max and min number
     * x, y function arguments
     */ 
    scanf("%d",&nCase);
    for(int k=1; k<=nCase;k++){ //taking number of test cases
        scanf("%d",&nInput); //number of input
        for(int i=0;i<nInput;i++){ //taking input numbers for each case
            scanf("%d",&number[i]);
        }
        maxmin(0,nInput-1,number,max,min); //array as pointer
        printf("Case: %d\n",k);
        printf("The max number is %d\n",max);
        printf("The min number is %d\n",min);
    }
    return 0;
}

void maxmin(int x, int y, int *number, int &max, int &min){
    if(y-x<=1){
        max=Max(number[x],number[y]);
        min=Min(number[x],number[y]);
    }else{
        int mid=(x+y)/2,max1,max2,min1,min2;
        /*
         * mid midle index
         * max1 , max2, min1, min2 temp variables
        */
        maxmin(x,mid,number,max1,min1);
        maxmin(mid+1,y,number,max2,min2);
        max=Max(max1,max2);
        min=Min(min1,min2);
    }
}
```

Input:

```
2
5
1 3 5 2 3
3
4 5 6
```

Output:

```
Case: 1
The max number is 5
The min number is 1
Case: 2
The max number is 6
The min number is 4
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void BasicRecurisonExample();
void getLargest(int tempArray[], int a_Size);
void getSmallest(int tempArray[], int a_Size);
int main()
{
   BasicRecurisonExample();
  return 0;
}




  void BasicRecurisonExample()
  {
     string input;
     int myArray[101];
     int array_Size = 101;

    for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
    {
      myArray[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;
    }


    getLargest(myArray, array_Size);

    cout << "\n\n";

    getSmallest(myArray, array_Size);

    cout << "\n\nDo you want to do another, if so type yes: ";
    getline(cin, input);

    if (input == "yes")
    {
       BasicRecurisonExample();
    }
}

  void getSmallest(int tempArray[], int a_Size)
  {
     int Smallest = tempArray[0];

     for (int i = 0; i < a_Size; i++)
     {
        if (tempArray[i] < Smallest)
        {
           Smallest = tempArray[i];
        }
    }
      cout << "The smallest Element is: " << Smallest;
 }



void getLargest(int tempArray[], int a_Size)
{
    int maxValue = 0;

     for (int i = 0; i < a_Size; i++)
     {
        if (tempArray[i] > maxValue)
        {
           maxValue = tempArray[i];
        }
     }
       cout << "The largest element is: " << maxValue;
 }
```

You're dealing with arrays, and loops which means you need to have logic to prevent that from being infinite because you can make this call itself infinitely by removing one if statement... This is recursive period end of story the leading void function calls it's self directly which is at it's most basic recursion.

There is no reason to over complicate some thing, for instance returning with a function call would be tail recursion.. Their is no need for that with this... All you have to do is type "yes" and it will call it's self again..

Answer (score -2):

Okay so Below you will find two functions, that when Called. Will find the largest and the smallest elements in the array. You will how ever have to change your main code to make these work if you want to use them..

Your main could look some thing like this.

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  using namespace std;
 int findSmallest(int tempArray[], int a_Size);
 int findLargest(int tempArray[], int a_Size);
 int main()
 {  
   int myArray[101];
   int array_Size = 101;

   for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
   {
       myArray[i] = rand() % 100 + 1; 
   }

cout << "The largest value in the array is: " << findLargest(myArray, array_Size) << endl;

cout << "The Smallest value in the array is: " << findSmallest(myArray, array_Size) << endl;

   return 0;
}


int findSmallest(int tempArray[], int a_Size)
{ 
       int Smallest = tempArray[0]; 

       for (int i = 0; i < a_Size; i++) 
           {
              if (tempArray[i] < Smallest) 
              {
                 Smallest = tempArray[i]; 
              }
           }

  return Smallest; 
}
```

Prototype this function and  test it, it will find the smallest number in your array.

```
int findLargest(int tempArray[], int a_Size)
{   
       int maxValue = 0;

       for (int i = 0; i < a_Size; i++) 
       {
             if (tempArray[i] > maxValue) 
             {
                maxValue = tempArray[i]; 
             }
       } 

  return maxValue;
}
```

And if you prototype and test that, it will find the larges element in your array!

Comment: Thank you, but it is not a recursive process.

Comment: Recurison is when a function calls its self, as I said you can manipulate this to your needs it was a basic example to show you how to manipulate an array to locate the smallest and or the largest element

Comment: I do not see any recursion in this solution. I see iteration of a for loop.

Comment: Recursion is when a function calls its self directly or indirectly, it's a basic concept that's currently being and almost always is completely over complicated. If you want to do this recursivley figure out why or how you want to force the function to call its self be it directly or indirectly. Recursion can be some thing as simple as 1. Create the array in a void. 2. create two functions to find a return the value of the smallest and large 3. Create a void to display the output and then use that to call the initial function that you want to be recursive.

Comment: Please point out where `findLargest` calls itself or where `findSmallest` calls itself. Also, recursion is a very simple concept that can be very elegant when used for an appropriate algorithm.

Comment: When I said it was recursive it was, and I had other functions listed there, I did how ever remove them and make it simpler. You'll notice in my answer not once did I claim it was recursive.... The solution I provided was a propper way to find the minimum and maximum value and the comment above yours is a basic explanation of recursion which apparently some people don't get lol.

Comment: @suroh no, looking at this history of your answer it never had them as recursive functions. If the question asks for a recursive version, then posting an iterative version is not generally useful. Note: Recursion is where a function calls itself, while an iterative solution uses loops without calling itself. And...  "create a void"?

Comment: I'm not going to sit here an argue with you lol.. I really could careless. In truth I added them and took them out because I can't stand having to format shit on this site, the only problem is because I forgot to edit the comment I made right after I got digital forum warriors like you focusing in on stupid little things ignoring the actually validity of what I've said because it's more important to people like you to fight with some one on the internet then actually try and help the guy asking the question, I wont even read what you type so feel free to waste your own time mate!

Comment: Furthermore you get people that want the answer but don't want to do the work, this guys code is going to end up being re-written and not by him but by some one trying to help him. If he took my two functions he could figure it out on his own with out having to change logic of finding the smallest or largest

Comment: @suroh if they need a recursive way to find the min and max values, then they *would* need to rewrite the functions because yours are iterative solutions (and I never said your code was wrong, just *wrong for this question*).

Comment: I added a recursive solution, in it's most basic form.... I'll say it again recursion simply put is a function that calls its self directly or indirectly.I gave him an example if he wants each function to be recursive which is completely pointless then he can use either of my two answers to better suite his issue.

Comment: Iterative = loops, Recursive = calling self, your code = iterative, question asks for = recursive.

Comment: your're missing some basic concepts here or I've been having a prolonged stroke for the last hour.  The OP wants to find the largest and smallest value in an array yes? Please explain to me how the OP is supposed to find those values with out walking through the array. The answer is simple if you don't already know it's location you can't. Recursive doesn't mean " yay I don't have to use logic any more " if you're suggesting that you can't use loops in a recursive function then your teachers failed you.

Comment: If the op wants both functions that are used to find the largest and smallest value he still needs to use logic, whether it's 5000 if else statements, a while, a for, a do while etc..  He says and I quote "To finding maximum & minimum in recursive way" doesn't specify that the two functions used to find the values are recursive all that means is that one function needs to be. If they do have to be recursive which is again pointless for some thing like this then all he has to do is add in a routine  that calls the functions when ever a value in the array is changed and you still need logic